# Dynamic Ranges using offset function

Tags: dynamic

```
Sub FIXPAY()

Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long, s2 As Worksheet

Set s2 = Sheets("Analysis")

s2.Select
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Copy
s2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
'*Copy the table header from 1st table and paste it to the second empty row.*    

Range("A3:C3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
s2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
'*Copy from A3:C3 to the last filled row and paste it to the row right below 
the heading.*    


s2.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDIRECT(""'""&RC1&""'!""&ADDRESS(ROW(R73C[-2]),COLUMN(R73C[-2])))"
'*Put the above formula in the D Column right below the heading*
```

> The problem lies here.How can I replace the below line with dynamic range such that it will auto-fill the data in the D Column

```
s2.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDIRECT(""'""&RC1&""'!""&ADDRESS(ROW(R73C[-2]),COLUMN(R73C[-2])))"

s2.Range("D15").AutoFill destination:=Range("D15:D" & Range("A15").End(xlDown).Row)

LastCol = Cells(14, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("D15", Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).FormulaR1C1 = Range("D15").FormulaR1C1

End Sub
```

Can someone please help me making the code fully dynamic? Please note that I have referenced as row 15 here because my heading of the second table is in row 14 and hence the formula from D15 is to be copied to the last filled row and last filled column.